# Check if ANY records in MySQL table lie on a particular date

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I have an online booking system database in mysql that i am trying to link in with a visual php calendar using [this tutorial](http://www.phpjabbers.com/how-to-make-a-php-calendar-php26.html).

Each day is represented on the calendar by a `<td>` and i use the following PDO query to determine what background colour should be for each day (if available = no colour, if not then red).

The one complication i have is that i need to visually show 1 booking to end on day X, and show another booking to start on that same day X.

```
$query_params = array( 
    ':campervan_id' => $_GET['campervan'],
    ':day' => $date_form.($i - $startday + 1)
);

$query = " 
    SELECT 
        car,
        booking_id,
        DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%e/%c') AS s_d,
        DATE_FORMAT(end_date, '%e/%c') AS e_d
    FROM 
        bookings as bb 
    INNER JOIN 
        reservation as br ON bb.booking_id=br.bookings_id
    INNER JOIN 
        cars as bc ON br.car_id=bc.car_id
    WHERE 
        bc.campervan_id=:campervan_id AND
        :day BETWEEN bb.start_date AND bb.end_date
";
```

with me then using the following to output the table cell result:

```
if($i < $startday) { 
    echo "
        <td>
        </td>
    ";
}

else {

// IF DAY IS AVAILABLE
if(!$rows) {
    $color = "none";
}
// IF DAY IS UNAVAILABLE
else {
    $color = "#F3747F";
}

$dayMonth = ($i-$startday + 1)."/$cMonth";


// If DAY FALLS ON A START PICK UP DATE
if ($dayMonth == $rows['s_d']) {
        $back = "background-image:url(\"images/morning_back.png\");";
        $color = "none";
}
// If DAY FALLS ON A END DROP OFF DATE
else if($dayMonth == $rows['e_d']) { 
        $back = "background-image:url(\"images/afternoon_back.png\");";
        $color = "none";
}

// **************************************************

// IF FALLS ON BOTH A START AND END DATE????????
else if($dayMonth == ($rows['s_d'] && $rows['e_d'])) { 
        $back = "background-image:url(\"images/full_back.png\");";
        $color = "none";
}

// **************************************************

else {
    $back = "";
}

echo "
    <td align='center' valign='middle' height='100px' width='134' style='color:#FFFFFF; background-color:".$color."; ".$back." border:1px solid white;'>
        ".($i-$startday + 1)."
    </td>
";
}
```

This works for visually showing a diagonal split background image on the start date of each booking, the end date for each but i cannot get the days where there is both an end of one booking and the start of another to show correctly.

I think it's because my initial query is only looking at one booking record - i need it to recognise all of them, can anyone help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make an inner join on bookings bb to itself where bb.enddate=bb2.stsrtdate and bb.booking_id!=bb2.booking_id

```
LEFT JOIN booking as bb2
ON bb.enddate=bb2.startdate 
AND bb.booking_id!=bb2.booking_id
```

You can then check if bb2.booking_id is null. if it is not, there is a matching start and end date.

But this will only work if there can be only 1 event starting in the same day. Else you could get duplicate rows.